# Re-expressing complex polynomials with division

Tags: complex-analysis

Using division, express the polynomial $z^3+2$ in the form: $$a_0+a_1(z-1)+a_2(z-1)^2+a_3(z-1)^3.$$

Typically, when I need to divide polynomials, I look for a common factor, but I don't see any in this polynomial. My strategy would be to treat this as a linear algebra problem and expand each quantity to solve for each $a_n$ term. Would that be necessary in this case or is there a simpler way to go about this?

Comment: What about the Taylor expansion? Why do you say by division?

Comment: Of course, it's so easy to forget the most straightforward solutions.

Comment: It becomes even more obvious if you do the change of variables $z-1=w$.
Then you're simply expanding $(w+1)^3+2$.

Comment: Thank you. I said using division since that's the concept we're covering in our complex analysis class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments, other methods are probably easier, but you certainly can do this by division if you wish.  We want
$$z^3+2=a_0+a_1(z-1)+a_2(z-1)^2+a_3(z-1)^3\ .\tag{$*$}$$
Dividing the LHS by $z-1$ gives
$$z^3+2=(z-1)(z^2+z+1)+3\ .$$
Looking at $(*)$, when we divide the RHS by $z-1$ the remainder is obviously $a_0$; for the LHS it is $3$ as we have just shown; so $a_0=3$.  Now in $(*)$, subtract $3$ from both sides and divide by $z-1$; we have already done the working so we just write down
$$z^2+z+1=a_1+a_2(z-1)+a_3(z-1)^2\ .$$
Now follow the same procedure to find $a_1$, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for showing the division method. While other methods are easier, understanding this will help with other problems.

Answer (score 1):

For $f(z)=z^{3}+2$, then $f(z)=f(1)+f'(1)(z-1)+\dfrac{f''(1)}{2!}(z-1)^{2}+\dfrac{f^{(3)}(1)}{3!}(z-1)^{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$z^3+2=a_0+a_1(z-1)+a_2(z-1)^2+a_3(z-1)^3.$$

$$ z=1 \implies a_0 =3$$ Differentiate, you get $$3z^2 =a_1+2a_2 (z-1)+ 3a_3(z-1)^2$$

$$ z=1 \implies a_1=3$$

Differentiate, you get

$$ 6z=2a_2+6a_3(z-1)$$

$$ z=1 \implies a_2=3$$

Differentiate, you get

$$ a_3 =1$$

Thus $$z^3+2=3+3(z-1)+3(z-1)^2+(z-1)^3.$$